# Что губит upload?

Tags: http, upload

Нужны идеи куда копать...
есть корпоративный портал, в локальной сети общается с внешним миром через ISA(или внешний мир с ним) и мапинг портов. работало всё великолепно несколько лет. и вот однажды случилоь нечто - перестали загружаться файлы на сервер портала. на сам портал приходит заголовок(?) от загрузки, но та часть где само тело файла отсутствует, а на клиенте ошибка 500 или обрыв коннекта.
если делать загрузку из локальной сети - всё нормально. как в таких случаях бывает - никто, ничего не менял :)

Comment: Кто отдаёт 500? Что в логах на сервере? Не используется ли где-то в этой схеме HTTPS/SSL/TLS?

Comment: 500 отдаёт сервер,
HTTPS/SSL/TLS не используется

Comment: Какой сервер? приведите заголовки ответа полностью.

Comment: сервер на tomcat
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.
The server cannot complete the request because it encountered an error.
Please try it again in a few minutes, or contact the server administrator.

Comment: Это текст, Вы заголовки смотрите. И логи.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Tue, 28 Apr 2015 17:59:26 GMT
Server: OpenCms/7.5.3
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Connection: close

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23273/discussion-between--and-antoniok).

Comment: У меня кончились идеи, найдите лог ошибкок, если он пишется, и изучайте его. Если не пишется - найдите, как его включить. Сам я с tomcat руками никогда не работал, поэтому конкретных путей не подскажу.